# Laravel validation fails when large files are uploaded

Tags: laravel, validation

I am passing three files and few other strings in my post request to the controller. But i don't know the reason why my validation fails.

Here is the form

```
<form>
  <input type="radio"  name="inter_fit" id="inter_good_fit" value = "good" >
  <input type="radio" name="inter_fit" id="inter_bad_fit" value = "bad">
  <input id="report_upload" type="file"/>
  <input id="skype_upload" type="file"/>
  <input id="audio_upload" type="file"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="comp_candidate_id"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="comp_profile_id"/>
</form>

var candidate_id =  $('#comp_candidate_id').val();
var profile_id =  $('#comp_profile_id').val();
var inter_fit = $("input[name=inter_fit]:checked").val();
var report_file = $("#report_upload").prop('files');
var skype_file = $("#skype_upload").prop('files');
var audio_file = $("#audio_upload").prop('files');
var dataString = 'inter_fit='  +inter_fit+ '&report_file='  +report_file+ '&skype_file='  +skype_file+ '&audio_file='  +audio_file+ '&candidate_id=' +candidate_id+ '&profile_id=' +profile_id;
console.log(dataString);
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("inter_fit",inter_fit);
formData.append("candidate_id",candidate_id);
formData.append("profile_id",profile_id);
var reportInput = $("#report_upload").get(0).files[0];

formData.append("report_file",reportInput);              

var skypeInput = $("#skype_upload").get(0).files[0];
formData.append("skype_file",skypeInput);              

var audioInput = $("#audio_upload").get(0).files[0];
formData.append("audio_file",audioInput); 

             $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/complete_interview",
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        showStatus(data)

                    },
                    error : function(xhr ,status ,error)
                    {
                        console.log(xhr);
                        console.log(status);
                        console.log(error);

                    }
                });

                function showStatus(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                }
```

When small files like text files are uploaded no problem occurs and it passes the validation. When the large files are uploaded the validation fails. Here is my controller code

```
public function completeInterview(Request $request){

        $val = \Validator::make($request->all(),
        ['inter_fit' => 'required',
        'report_file' => 'required',
        'skype_file' => 'required',
        'audio_file' => 'required', //not passed
        'candidate_id' => 'required',
        'profile_id' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($val->fails()) {            
        return response()->json(['msg'=>"val_failed"]);
      }
      }
```

I have changed the PHP file upload and max post size configuration. I don't understand what is the issue here.

I always get the response as **val_failed**.

Comment: Why don't you actually print out the validation errors so you know why it's failing? `$errors = $val>errors(); dd($errors->all());`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer will solve your question but, add in your form element the **enctype** like this:

```
<form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

When you make a POST request, you have to encode the data that forms the body of the request in some way. See [this question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean/) for more about `enctype`.

Furthermore, add

```
'audio_file' => 'required|mimes:mpga',
```

to the validate section.

Comment: Do any of the other fields have data in them?

Comment: Try 'mimes:mpga' for mp3 files. in the validate section. Like This 'file' => 'required|mimes:mpga'

Comment: Did you find out the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Form::open` method has `'files' => true` that means form data will be encoded as "multipart/form-data" so it is required whenever you are going to upload any files with form data.

Example:
http://www.expertphp.in/article/laravel-53-upload-image-with-validation-example